# Fix background and put panel over it

Tags: html, css

Good evening,

I'm very new to html and was searching for a solution but I did not found any. So what I'm trying to do is to fix the background and put something like a panel over it, where I do the rest of the site like text etc. I have an example website: https://420cheats.com
I don't know if I am right but I think I have to add a second class and put this somehow over the background

Thanks in advance.

Ps: I did the background as a class in the css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set a fixed background-image on your body element. Both the `<body>` and `<html>` tag need a set height of 100% for this to work.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170407220921-07-iconic-mountains-pitons-restricted.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.content {
  background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.5);
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto 20px auto; /* top right bottom left */
  height: 1500px; /* remove this, just here to show that it works */
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  
   <h1>Content</h1>  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The code works perfectly but there is just one little thing... When I'm changing the opacity for the class it will automatically change for the header to. I think I have to do a third class or something like that and tie it on the content class.

Comment: @tableware Which is? :)

Comment: I didn't know that when you press enter it will automatically send it haha. I posted the problem above.

Comment: @tableware This is a stupid thing in css, opacity cannot be removed from child elements without some hacky solutions. Using rgb for the background color with a fourth parameter (which is the opacity) will be the easier solution. You'll have to convert hex to rgb which you can do [here](https://www.rgbtohex.net/hextorgb/). Answer is updated.

Comment: Nope, in the CSS `background-color: #ccc` is changed to `background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.5);` (0.5 being the opacity of the div)

Comment: Yes you right, did it and it's works perfectly, thank you very much

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the background as fixed and create a DOM element to lay on top of your background image.

```css
body {
 background: url('https://cdn-image.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/1600x1000/public/1507062474/hotel-everest-namche-nepal-mountain-lodge-MOUNTAIN1017.jpg?itok=g-S4SL9n') no-repeat fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 
}

div {
 padding: 20px;
 width: 400px;
 height: 1200px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```